# mock contents of a required json file

Tags: react-native, jestjs

At the top, I have the following in a javascript app:

```
    const d = require('files/file1.json)


   export class Processor{

     getTag(){
      //process data
     return tag;
     }
   }
```

where files is defined in package.json of the directory where the files are located and working. file1.json contains just string keys with numbers. I want to mock those values for each test case but so far I can't:

```
    it("should tag data as red", () =>{

         jest.mock(
           "files/file1.json",
          () => mockedJsonData
          );

      const p = new Processor()
      expect(p.getTag()).toEqual('red')
    });

   it("should tag data as blue", () =>{

         jest.mock(
           "files/file1.json",
          () => mockedJsonDataBlue
          );

      const p = new Processor()
      expect(p.getTag()).toEqual('blue')
    });
```

Since the file exists, I didn't do virtual true but even with it, the mocked data is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

`jest.mock` inside tests cannot affect `d` because it has been already imported.

For test-specific mocks relevant modules should be imported inside tests:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});

it("should tag data as red", () =>{
  jest.mock(".../file1.json", ...);
  const d = require('.../file1.json);
  ...
});
```

If `Processor` captures `d` at top-level, it should be defined for each test too, or moved to helper module.